# переход по ссылкам добавляет лишние части в url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc, router

Доброго времени суток, есть такой .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

и ссылки в меню вида `index/index`, `index/about`, ... то есть контроллер/экшен.
Предполагается что должно получатся вроде такого:

```
http://localhost/index/index
http://localhost/index/about
```

Проблема в том что, при переходе по ссылкам добавляется лишний `index/` в юрл.
 
Допустим при запуске есть `http://localhost`, при переходе по ссылке есть `http://localhost/index/index`, еще 1 переход уже `http://localhost/index/index/index`, еще 1 получается `http://localhost/index/index/index/index` и т.д. 
Подозреваю что исправляется в .htaccess

`*index` - название контроллера, может быть любым.

Со ссылками вида `?url=index/index` все отрабатывает нормально.

Поиск в яндекс ничего не дал, просмотрел кучу всего про .htaccess но тут даже правильно сформулировать вопрос яндексу не могу.

Comment: контроллер/экшен - это zend у вас?

Comment: нет, обычная самописная mvc

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодится. Ссылки надо писать со слешем "/" вот так "/index/index" а не "index/index". Почему - хз.

Comment: Дайте более подробный ответ. Вы же сами написали в вопросе -  "?url=index/index все отрабатывает нормально".

Comment: Вот и дожили, "программисты" делают сайтики и сами не понимают как это работает. Теорию читать не пробовали? Если относительная ссылка начинается со слэша, то это ссылка относительно хоста и адресом из ссылки заменяется часть адреса после хоста, а если ссылка без слэша в начале, то это ссылка относительно текущей страницы и адрес из ссылки добавляется в конец текущего адреса.

Comment: Да там нечего более подробно... ссылки вида ?url=index/index работали как обычный GET параметр localhost/index.php?url=index/index, естественно все работало. А мне нужно было адреса вида localhost/index/about/... и здесь помог слеш /index/index

Comment: @kot-da-vinci а может человек делает не коммерческий сайт, а просто учится? Такой вариант не рассматривали?